# cargar select dinamicamente con selec2

Tags: javascript

alguien sabe como obtener los valores del buscador de `select2`, y agregarle un evento keyup para detectar cuando se escriba una tecla y asi traer los datos dinámicos desde una `json` o una `api` que devuelva un `json`. porque ya cargue los datos al `select` pero son como 20000 y el `select` se pone muy lento.

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];

$("#selectid").select2({
  data: data//asi cargo los datos pero son como 20000
})
```

ya intente agregándole eventos keyup y otros asi:

```
$('#selectepspri').keyup(function(e){
            console.log("pero esto no lo detecta supongo que los select no tinen este 
                       evento");
})
```

Comment: Buenos días compañero, por lo que he estado observando, se puede realizar una carga de datos desde ajax para así mandar a un api la información para filtrar... https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax acá tienes varios ejemplos de cómo hacerlo. Un saludo!
PD: Si no lo ves claro, avísame y te preparo un ejemplo cuando termine de trabajar.

Comment: hola, me podrías colaborar con un ejemplo para consultarlos con un json como el que di en el ejemplo, porque con el ejemplo de select2 usan la api de github que creo que ya devuelve filtrado los datos. entonces tendria que crear una api para devolver los registros y utilizarlos en select2

Comment: Buenas compañero, para facilitarte un ejemplo, tendría que hacer yo el api y filtrarlo, eso ya es algo que debes hacer, además, que todo depende del lenguaje que uses en el back. Con los ejemplos que aparecen en la web de select2, ya hacen la llamada al back, y ahí, podrás hacer las búsquedas con los filtros pasados. Un saludo!

Comment: Para el API, tendrás que leer el json, y cargarlo en un array... Una vez tengas el array, filtrar dicho array y devolver un array filtrado. Si subes el código que hagas si no te funciona, con gusto te ayudaré, pero lo que planteas no es una duda, es hacerlo directamente.